# How to call a function of another window in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I open a new tab using window.open. The new tab has a javascript `myfunction` function in it defined in a script tag. From the window that opens the new window, I want to run that function.

How can I do that?

Thanks

Something like

```
var a = window.open("mypage.html", "_blank");
a.myfunction("hi");
```

**EDIT**

This isn't working. Its not doing the alert.

opener

```
        var w = window.open("../scripts/map.php", "_blank");
        w.postMessage("The user is 'bob' and the password is 'secret'", "*");
```

new tab

```
        function receiveMessage(event) {
            alert(event.data);
        }
        window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
```

Comment: Try using window.opener

Comment: How do I write the code exactly?

Comment: you can try a.postMessage and handle the message in that window. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage

Comment: I think I misunderstood....you want to run myFunction, which is defined in the newly opened window, from the window that opened the new tab, right? It's not that you want to run a function in the opener window from the newly opened window, correct?

Comment: Do you want to run myFunction at any given time or only when the new window is opened?

Comment: when the new window opens

Comment: @user1600124: it didn't work. I put my code above.

Comment: hmm.. what browser are you using?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
var a = window.open("mypage.html", "_blank");
a.focus();

a.addEventListener('load', function(){
  a.myfunction("hi");
}, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a php file provides the content for the new window:

```
window.open('http://www.example.com/myFile.php?parameter=' + parameter, 'myWindow', 'width=500,height=500,scrollbars=yes').focus();
```

Then in the php section of myFile.php:

```
$myParam = (isset($_GET['parameter'])) ? $_GET['parameter'] : null;
```

Then using a body onload call a function:

```
<head>
<script>
    var myParam = '<?= $myParam ?>';
</script>
</head>
<body onload="myFunction()">
```

The function tests for the existence of $myParam:

```
function myFunction() {
    if (myParam) {
        //do Something
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't want to attach it as a url parameter. The accepted answer works good though.