# how to detect window.open

Tags: javascript, window.open

I am trying to solve a scenario and let me try to explain using an example. I have a script which tries to open a new url using window.open method. This script triggers a window open after 5 sec without any click event from the user. What I would like to do is .. capture the window open method. Is there any function available like addEventListener to capture window open method? I would like to track a window.open which was not initiated by user action.

Thanks
Lynn

```
setTimeout(function(){
window.open(url,name);
}, 5000);
```

Comment: There is a answer.See if this help to you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/25517913/9555996

Comment: the 'load' will not capture the window.open, it MAY capture the load of the page in that window IF the browser will allow it

Comment: @DarshanaPathum To attach to the load, you need to modify the window object that is inside the setTimeout, that defeats the requirements of OP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace it

NOTE: window.open does not work at stackoverflow due to sandboxing
Also a window.open not triggered by a user action will likely be suppressed by the browser

```js
const saveOpen = window.open;
window.open = function(url,windowName,parms) {
  console.log("triggered",url);
  saveOpen(url, windowName || "",parms || "")
};
const url = "https://stackoverflow.com", windowName="myWin"
setTimeout(function(){
  window.open(url,windowName);
}, 1000);
```

As mentioned in [How to call a function of another window in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25517800/how-to-call-a-function-of-another-window-in-javascript) you could attach a load event listener to the window:

```js
const loaded = function(str) { console.log(str) },
url = "https://stackoverflow.com", windowName="myWin";
setTimeout(function(){
  const w = window.open(url,windowName);
  if (w) w.addEventListener('load',function() { loaded(url)})
  else console.log('sorry, not allowed'); // this of course can be a call to whatever
}, 1000);
```

Comment: thank you so much. this works.

Comment: The second example shows something you are likely not interested in, because it modifies the setTimeout and you want to intercept no matter where window.open is called

Comment: yes.. i want to track window.open whenever it is called.